# php not converting ascii to utf-8 correctly

Tags: php, utf-8

php : `7.3`

laravel : `7`

the problem is i'm getting information with `curl` from some websites and the output is something like this:

```
&#1607;&#1705;&#1587; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1608;&#1585; : &#1782;&#1777;&#1643;&#1783;&#1780;&#1785;&#1643;&#1776;&#1776;&#1776; &#1578;&#1608;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606;
```

when i return it from laravel or print it in some page it will be something like this:

```
آداک : ۵۸٫۳۴۴٫۰۰۰ تومان پارسان می : ۵۸٫۴۵۰٫۰۰۰ تومان های اپل : ۵۸٫۴۹۹٫۰۰۰ تومان تکسنولی : ۵۸٫۸۸۸٫۰۰۰ تومان لوتوس : ۵۹٫۰۹۹٫۰۰۰ تومان گجت : ۵۹٫۳۰۰٫۰۰۰ تومان های اپل : ۵۹٫۹۹۹٫۰۰۰ تومان آروند : ۶۱٫۰۸۰٫۰۰۰ تومان هکس استور : ۶۱٫۷۴۹٫۰۰۰
```

and its ok.

but i want to send it in telegram , and when i send it the output is looks like this:

[image]

i tried to figured out what encoding is whit `mb_detect_encoding` and its says its `ASCII` and also i tried to convert it to utf-8 but its seems ASCCI is kind of utf-8 and any way its driving me crazy.

this are some methods i tried and none of them works.

```php
iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $text); // output : the same ascii charachters and after it when detect it with mb_detect_encoding its says it is ASCII yet

utf8_encode($text) // output : the same ascii charachters and after it when detect it with mb_detect_encoding its says it is ASCII yet

mb_convert_encoding($text,'utf-8' , 'ascii'); // output : the same ascii charachters and after it when detect it with mb_detect_encoding its says it is ASCII yet

// i also used forcetoutf8 package
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;
$utf8_string = Encoding::toUTF8($utf8_or_latin1_or_mixed_string);
// but the output was same
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `&#1606;` is ASCII, because this relates to the text encoding, not what all those characters together might mean. What you have here is one HTML entity and it must be decoded into the character they represent.

In PHP you'd use [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) on an entire text. See also [Wikipedia: HTML > Entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references).